# Vector Ruggedness Measure (VRM) tool does not add output map to display?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, tools

I'm trying to use Vector Ruggedness Measure (VRM) tool with ArcMap 10.2.2 an the tool runs somewhat smoothly, but the output raster won't show in the chosen folder. Tool creates slope and aspect rasters and the output raster shows in the result window, but when I click add to display from result window, nothing happens.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate whether you are using the same tool that is discussed in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110397/how-to-use-outdated-arcscripts, please?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same tool as in that topic.I was able to fix the problem with additional updates and installing the tool again, so thanks for your interest!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).